# Can RF power measurement be done using a temperature probe?

Tags: temperature, power-measurement

Can RF power (at HF frequencies in the range of 0 to 40 dBm into a 50 Ohm load) be measured by a thermometer or other temperature measurement device on the termination load?

If so, what kind of temperature probe should be used?  What might be the environmental considerations around the termination load?  And how might the accuracy of this method of power measurement compare to using a scope probe to estimate sinusoidal voltage (Vpp) across the load?

Comment: [Yes.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microwave_power_meter#Thermal)  They've been around a long time, and generally work very well.

Comment: Yes, it's called a [bolometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolometer), and is a fundamental method of transferring calibration between DC and AC power standards.

Answer (score 1):

HP aka Keysight use to make rf power meters using thermocouple heads. You might search their app notes and see what they may have to say about construction of the probes. Outfits now make power meter probes connected to a PC via USB to measure power.

Answer (score 1):

> Can RF power (at HF frequencies in the range of 0 to 40 dBm into a 50 Ohm load) be measured by a thermometer or other temperature measurement device on the termination load?

yes. Temperature measurement is one of the ways RF powers are measured – though that is an approach typically reserved to really large powers (or historically, very wide bandwidths, where everything else is complicated), or very nicely integrated systems that isolate the measurement device very much from the environments. 0-20 dBm is not really that regime, but the same principle still applies.

But: you need to calibrate this. You can theoretically calculate the thermal resistance (and hence the factor between difference to ambient temperature and load temperature) of a black-painted resistive load in a disturbance-free box, but honestly, that's more or less guessing, since you'd need to know the shape, air pressure, circulation, reflectivity of surroundings, thermal conductivity of your connections, and the environmental temperature (and I'm sure a lot of other things) to a high degree of accuracy if you want to do this with low powers.

So, honestly, this sounds way way more work than it's worth; if you can calibrate that chamber you need to build, then you could also calibrate an RTL dongle (or really, whatever receives your signal and is able to calculate power) with maybe external attenuators, and be done with it (you'd still want to control the temperature of the device, as that influences gain, but that control is much laxer than what you'd need to measure 5 dBm).

Other than that:

- [My answer](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/16311/how-to-make-an-rf-probe-for-accurate-power-measurement-at-qrp-power-levels/16316#16316) to "*How to make an RF probe for accurate power measurement at QRP power levels?*"